# Uniqueness of a point where the chord coincides with the tangent

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, convex-analysis, convexity-inequality

Let  $F:[0,1] \to [0,\infty)$ be a $C^2$ function satisfying $F(1)=0, F'(1)=0$, which is strictly strictly decreasing on $[0,1]$. Suppose that for some $a \in(0,1)$,  $F'' < 0$ on $[0,a)$ and $F'' > 0$ on $(a,1]$.

> I am trying to prove that there exist a **unique** point $s \in (a,1]$ satisfying satisfying $\frac{F(s)-F(0)}{s-0}=F'(s)$.

I have a proof for the existence (see below), but I am having trouble with establishing uniqueness. I vaguely remember that I had an argument for that, but somehow I can't reconstruct what it was exactly.

*Proof of existence:*

Define $H(s)=\frac{F(s)-F(0)}{s-0}-F'(s)$. Then $H(1)=-F(0)<0$. The concavity of $F$ on $[0,a)$ implies that $H(s) >0$ on $(0,a)$. Indeed $H(s)=F'(\theta(s))$ for some $\theta(s) \in (0,s)$ and $F'$ is decreasing on $(0,a)$. By the intermediate value theorem $H(s)$ must be zero for some $s \in (a,1]$.

---

*I am actually interested in proving this under the weaker assumption that $F \in C^1, F|_{[0,a]},F|_{[a,1]} \in C^2$ but the second derivatives do not agree at $a$.

---

Comment: Yes, it starts positive end decreases to zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the function $h(x) = F(x) - x F'(x)-F(0)$. Then

- $h(a) > 0$ because $F$ is strictly concave on $[0, a]$,
- $h(1) = -F(0) < 0$,
- $h'(x) = -xF''(x) < 0$ on $(a, 1]$, so that $h$ is strictly decreasing on $[a, 1]$.

This implies that there is a unique point $s \in (a, 1)$ satisfying
$$
 h(s) = 0 \iff \frac{F(s)-F(0)}{s-0} = F'(s) \, .
$$

Comment: Thanks! great answer. After some further thought, I now wonder whether there always exist such a point $s$, even when $F'(1) \neq 0$ (in that case $F'(1)<0$ since $F$ is decreasing). Looking at your analysis, this seems to happen if and only if $h(1)=-F'(1)-F(0)\le 0$ or equivalently $F'(1)\ge -F(0)$. Do you have an idea if this always happens? I asked about it here separately here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3825345/does-this-inequality-on-the-derivative-always-hold

Comment: @AsafShachar: I am fairly sure that this is wrong. If $F$ is strictly concave on $[0, a]$ and linear on $[a, 1]$ then $F(0) < -F'(1)$. Now you can modify that slightly to make $F$ strictly concave on $[a, 1]$.

Comment: Thanks, I agree with you.